# Solve : $y'=\frac{y^2}{xy-9}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve :

$y'=\frac{y^2}{xy-9}$

My solution :

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^2}{xy-9} \implies (xy-9)dy=(y^2)dx\implies (xy-9)dy-(y^2)dx=0$

Denote $P=xy-9, Q=-y^2$.

$\frac{P_x-Q_y}{Q}=\frac{3y}{-y^2}=-\frac{3}{y}$ , does not depend on x.

The integrating factor $\mu=e^{-\int -\frac{3}{y}}=y^3$

$y^3(xy-9)dy-y^3(y^2)dx=(xy^4-9y^3)dy-(y^5)dx=0$

This is not an exact ode, where am I getting wrong ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ (xy-9)dy-(y^2)dx=0$$
$$y(xdy-ydx)-9dy=0$$
$$-yd\left (\dfrac {x}{y}\right)-\dfrac 9 {y^2}dy=0$$
$$d \left(\dfrac {x}{y}\right)+\dfrac 9 {y^3}dy=0$$
Integrate.

---

You made a sign mistake with the integrating factor:
$$\mu = \dfrac 1 {y^3}$$
Write the DE as
$$Pdx+Qdy=0$$
$$y^2dx- (xy-9)dy=0$$
And apply the formula for the integrating factor.
$$(\ln \mu)'= \dfrac {Q_x-P_y}P$$
$$\implies \mu= \dfrac 1 {y^3}$$

Comment: Thanks, could you see where am I getting wrong by solving this ode as an exact ode?

Comment: The formula for the integrating factor  seems wrong Check it for the integrating factorand write the DE as $Pdx+Qdy=0$ @erez

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use $\frac{P_x-Q_y}{y}$ instead of $\frac{P_x-Q_y}{Q}$.